# Are high frequency signals bad for circuits?

Tags: frequency, decoupling-capacitor

Why do we need capacitors connected to the ground when there is a high frequency signal? Are high frequency signals bad for circuits?

Comment: Why don't you glance through the wiki article on this (from a simple google search), then come back and ask a specific question.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor

Comment: *Unwanted* high frequency signals can be bad. There are also regulations concerning *emitted* high frequency signals.

Comment: Capacitors can be connected lots of ways, wheather there are "high" frequencies (whatever that means) or not.  This question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @pjc: Unwanted low frequencies are also bad.  Anything unwanted is, by definition, noise.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer - we need capacitors connected to ground to get rid of high frequency signal components where they are not wanted, for example, on power supplies that should be stable. The higher the frequency, the more a capacitor looks like a short circuit. Not the whole story, but as I said, the basic

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application. You typically want decoupling caps to stabilize your supply voltage. Otherwise there is the possibility, that peaks in the current consumption decreases the voltage under an threshold, where your ICs won't work any more.
In addition, any noise on the supply rail will cause some additional noise on your signals. If there are any analog signals, you typically want to avoid that.
Last but not least any rf parts of your supplies will start radiating from your circuit. This decreases effiency and, even worse, can cause trouble on other devices. This is why there is a EMI law that defines the maximum power, which your device is allowed to radiate on a given frequency.